# What is the correct status code for a RESTful resource when the request method is allowed, but the action cannot be completed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, http-status-codes

... due to server-side rules.

Specifically, I have comments that nest, and I am forbidding the deletion of comments with children.

So when someone requests:

```
DELETE /comments/5
```

where the 5th comment has children, I do not allow the comment to be deleted. What is the appropriate HTTP status code? I use a `405` elsewhere on the site, but that doesn't appear appropriate here. Nor is a `401` appropriate in cases where the user WOULD have rights to delete the comment (for instance if the user owns the comment), if it weren't for the children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about sending `409`. It translates to `The request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the resource.`

Comment: Ahh, I've reread the specification and agree with your assessment of the situation. Thanks!

Comment: Link to RFC definition of 409 Conflict: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10.4.10